# How to run IISExpress and other tasks at the same time from Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to run IISExpress and a unit test at the same time.

I've not used Powershell before but as it seems like a good fit I felt it would be jolly fun to learn a little.

I believe I've failed immediately.

My trivial piece of code is

```
Set-Location -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express"
.\iisexpress /site:SP                                                    #this works
vstest.console "UnitTestProject1\bin\debug\UnitTestProject1.dll"       #never gets hit
Read-Host -Prompt "Errors detected. Press enter to close."
```

The problem I have with this, although it starts IISExpress fine, it (the code) seems to wait there and not progress...

How do I get it to run both iisExpress and the vstest?

Comment: `Start-Process`; it will not wait for the process to end (unless you ask for it with `-Wait`). Your test stands a good chance of failing if IIS Express doesn't start quickly enough, though, so you may need to make it a bit more robust (or maybe loop an `Invoke-WebRequest` until it succeeds).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Start-Process` to launch the executable:

```
Start-Process emacs test.txt
```